# Custom UICollectionViewCell Subview Layout Issue

Tags: uilabel, autolayout, ios8, xcode6, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell class that sets the background view of the cell to a downloaded image and also a UILabel added to it that sits neatly at the bottom of the cell and is slightly transparent (this label is the title of the image). It looks great in portrait but when I rotate my device to landscape the UILabel stays in its position while the custom cell resizes itself to better fit the screen. I have my UILabel fully constrained to the cell so I don't know why it isn't resizing to always fit the width of the cell whether the device is in portrait/landscape.

I've attached these pictures below to better illustrate what exactly is happening:

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - for anyone who is also wondering the same thing, this is what I did:

I overrode the layoutSubviews method in my custom UICollectionViewCell class and forced my UILabel to stick to width and bottom of the cell.

It was weird because before I upgraded to xCode 6 and iOS 8 this was working perfectly without the need of this solution (the constraints within the storyboard worked), but now I had to use this approach.

Cheers!

Comment: I had a similar issue, but it was working on some devices, but not others.